# How to interact with twilio inbound message (from user) within python?

Tags: python, flask, twilio, flask-sqlalchemy, twilio-api

Hey guys I'm having trouble interacting with messages from users of a Twilio StudioFlow I've created. Throughout the execution, I want my program to recognize when a user sends a message such as "stop", or "start" so that it updates the database with the user's response.

My question is what are the tools I am missing to be able to interact with the inbound message within my code? I am using flask to build what would be an sms chatbot, and from the twilio docs I've come up with this:

```
# Imports of routes.py file 

from flask import request, redirect
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
from smsint.models import Part, parts, phone_nums
from smsint import app, db, client, sid, token

@app.route('/sms', methods=['POST', 'GET']) # route for main chat service
def flow():

    week_1 = client.studio.flows('FWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX').executions.create(to='+XXXXXXXXXX',
                                                                                         from_='+XXXXXXXXXX') # studioflow execution for first week

    # TwiML Resp
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    msg = resp.message

    # message user sent from twilio
    body = request.values.get('Body').lower()
    number = request.values.get('From')
    part = Part.query.filter_by(phone_num=number).first()

    # logic
    if body == 'stop':
        part.stop = True
        db.session.commit()

    elif body == 'start':
        part.stop = False
        db.session.commit()

    # ------- SAMPLE CODE ---------
    # Possible call to database phone numbers
    '''
    numbers = Part.query.with_entities(Part.phone).all()

    for i in phone_nums:
        execution = client.studio.v1.flows('FWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX').executions.create(
            to=i, from_='+XXXXXXXXXXX')
        execution
    '''
    # ------- SAMPLE CODE ---------
```

As you see I am using request from flask but I am sure I am not using it right because from testing I am returned a `NoneType` object from `body = request.values.get('Body').lower()`, and the same with `number` as well.

So to conclude, how can I interact with the properties of inbound messages (the "from" number, the body of the message) to my StudioFlow execution within my python code, using flask request or another module like the requests module itself?

Comment: How are you having the Studio flow communicate back to your controller? Are you using the HTTP Request Widget or the Run Function Widget with an HTTP request library?

Comment: I am using the HTTP Request Widget since I believe the Run Function Widget only allows for node.js code. I know the HTTP Request Widget has HTTP parameters that from what I understand allow your program to interact with data from the StudioFlow but I've been failing to understand the docs guidance on this: https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/http-request

Comment: The easiest way to see what you are getting from the HTTP Request Widget is use a tool like Ngrok, https://ngrok.com/, and once running, visit the debug web server it sets up, http://127.0.0.1:4040/, and see what you get from the webhook. Couple of different Twilio blogs using Ngrok, here is one, https://www.twilio.com/blog/automating-ngrok-python-twilio-applications-pyngrok.

Comment: Hey Alan thanks for the help and the reference. To focus more on the my last line about getting `None` for `request.values.get('Body')`. For some reason, I am not being returned a value when I declare this var. Do you have any insight on what might be wrong?

Comment: Were you able to see what Twilio is sending to your app? To confirm it is indeed sending something called Body?

Comment: So from running in PyCharm, I get a `werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'From'`.    From ngrok, I get a 500 Internal Server Error. So I'm thinking for some reason the `request.values.get('From')` or `request.form['From']` is not working to refer to the parameter key that twilio sends to my webhook and I have no idea why :(

Comment: What do you see as the key:value pairs sent from Twilio from the Ngrok debug interface http://127.0.0.1:4040/?

Comment: Firstly, didn't know ngrok had this page so thanks. I'm seeing a bunch of html for every call I've made to a webhook **(POST/.... , `500 INTERNAL ERROR`   , 51.3ms)**. I'm noticing that when I have the HTTP Request Widget set to Form, I don't get anything. But when its set to Application/JSON, Query Parameters show up on ngrok under that call and I see an empty `{}`. From this, I'm starting to see what mat be the issue and I'll let you know if I fix it.

Comment: Hey Alan I've resolved the issue. Turns out I had to configure the HTTP Request Widget with HTTP Parameters in the key-value options with a name as the key and liquid template lang as the value referring to the `To` parameter of a previous widget. Please feel free to post your answer as an answer so I can check mark it and close this post. Thank you so much!